# Where is "UPPER ONE QUARTER BLOCK" letter in Unicode?

Tags: unicode

In fact we have

```
U+2581  ▁   e2 96 81    LOWER ONE EIGHTH BLOCK  
U+2582  ▂   e2 96 82    LOWER ONE QUARTER BLOCK     
U+2583  ▃   e2 96 83    LOWER THREE EIGHTHS BLOCK   
U+2584  ▄   e2 96 84    LOWER HALF BLOCK    
U+2585  ▅   e2 96 85    LOWER FIVE EIGHTHS BLOCK    
U+2586  ▆   e2 96 86    LOWER THREE QUARTERS BLOCK  LOWER THREE QUARTER BLOCK
U+2587  ▇   e2 96 87    LOWER SEVEN EIGHTHS BLOCK
```

But only

```
U+2580  ▀   e2 96 80    UPPER HALF BLOCK
U+2594  ▔   e2 96 94    UPPER ONE EIGHTH BLOCK
```

But I really need all symmetric letters.

The question is not "how do it right" but "why" the things such as they are.

P.S. If somebody knows "how" -- write it down too:)

Comment: Seems you have to some tricks with colors: `LOWER THREE QUARTERS BLOCK` = invers `UPPER QUARTER BLOCK`

Comment: @Trinimon only if you can somehow manage to set the foreground color to match the terminal's background color, which isn't likely and definitely will not work in general

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why there isn't a complete set of block drawing characters can be found in [Chapter 22 of the Unicode standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode7.0.0/ch22.pdf):

> The Block Elements block (U+2580..U+259F) contains another collection
>   of graphic compatibility characters. [...] These elements were used to create crude graphic
>   displays in terminals or in terminal modes on displays where bit-mapped graphics were
>   unavailable.
>
> The fractional fills do
>   not form a logically complete set but are intended only for backward compatibility.

Because they are compatibility characters, their use is not encouraged.

Comment: So what should we use instead?

Answer (score 3):

*Upper One Quarter Block* was approved as part of Unicode 13.0 in 2020 along with a number of other block variations.

https://unicode-table.com/en/1FB82/

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Name | Upper One Quarter Block |
| Unicode number | `U+1FB82` |
| HTML-code | `&#129922;` |
| CSS-code | `\1FB82` |
| Block | Symbols for Legacy Computing |
| Unicode version | 13.0 (2020) |